# Merging boundaries with boundary shapefile in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.5, boundaries

I have a boundary shapefile of a city with 19 district boundaries, and I need to reflect some changes and create 16 districts instead.

Boundaries I want to merge are all neighboring districts (two neighboring districts need to become one).

I'm a beginner so I'm not sure what I should be doing to get at this, please give me some advice! I'm using ArcMap 10.5

[image][image]

Comment: Which GIS application are you using?

Comment: @whyzar Arcmap 10.5

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Are you adjusting the position of the boundaries at all, or are you just wanting to merge existing polygons?

Comment: @Midavalo Just merging, about 3 pairs in total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start Editing

[image]

Select two districts you want to merge into one, and from the Editor toolbar menu select "Merge"

[image]

A dialog will appear for you to select which record to copy attributes from - select the one you want to keep attributes and click OK

[image]

Your selected polygons will now be merged.  Repeat for the other districts you would like to merge.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response, I managed to do it!! thank you x 1000